# fs.readFile find a placehold and replace, Handlebars js also an option if need be

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, node.js-fs

I currently load a file in node with fs.readFileSync:

const filename = 'test.html';
const html_code = fs.readFileSync(`/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/html/${filename}`, 'utf8');

in test.html I have this div:

```
<div id="g-ai0-1" class="g-Text g-aiAbs g-aiPointText" style="top:59.6648%;margin-top:-14.2px;left:49.9587%;margin-left:-46px;width:92px;">
    <p class="g-pstyle0">{{ Text }}</p>
</div>
```

Is there away I can search the html for the `{{ Text }}` string and replace it with something else?
I tried this:

```
html_code.replace('{{ Text }}', 'new string');
```

This doesn't work and I also tried:

```
const html_code = fs.readFile(`/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/html/${filename}`, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if(err) {
          res.send(`this is the error: ${err}`);
          console.error(err)
          return
      }
      data.replace('{{ Text }}', 'new string');
      return data;
  });
```

Which also doesn't work.  How can I accomplish this with or with out an engine like handlebars?

Comment: readFileSync doesnt accept a third callback argument, try readFile instead (if the purpose is to make async call). In addition, .replace in JS only replace the first instance, try regex instead: `/{{ Test }}/g`, where g is flag for global replace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`fs.readFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilesyncpath-options) doesnt accept a third callback argument, it is synchronous and is returned directly to the `html_code` variable that you assigned to. (The one that accepts 3 arguments is [`fs.readFile()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fsreadfilepath-options-callback) but it is asynchronous.)

In addition, [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) in JS only replace the first instance, try regex instead: `/{{ Test }}/g`, where `g` is flag for global replace. The function also doesn't replace the string in-place but rather return a new string with the substring replaced. The code below should works fine:

```js
try {
  const html_code = fs.readFileSync(
    `/var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/html/${filename}`,
    'utf8'
  );
  const replaced_html = html_code.replace(/{{ Text }}/g, 'new string');
  // Do something with your replaced HTML
} catch (err) {
  res.send(`this is the error: ${err}`);
  console.error(err);
  return;
}
```